# How to open a Link in FullScreen on a iOS device?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I want to send some links to people for open a WebApp. But then it opens in Safari.

Is it possible to Start the App with the **first opening** in FullScreen-Mode?

Yes i know i can achieve this with a few meta-tags and when i add the site to my home-screen. This is great but for my case it would be a better experience when they can start in FullScreenMode withoud adding a shortcut.

It would be great when the user opens the link and then he should be asked if he wants to got to FullScreenMode. And when he accept this, then it should go in FullScreenMode. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** a "better experience". When you click a link, you expect a web page to opens, not a full screen app.

There is [Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android), if user visit your website often, a popup will appear to ask if they wish to add the web page to home screen, then your app can start in full screen if user open the app from home screen.

Web App Manifest does not works on iOS (yet), but you can try that on an Android phone with Chrome/Opera browser.

Comment: This is why i wrote: The user should be asked if he want to go to FullscreenMode.